# Multiple Range Keys For Single Hash Key In DynamoDB

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have the items as follows with different Company Names and records ( Records count is around 110K ):

```
Items=[{"Company":"ABCD","Frequency":"Annual","Date":"2016-03-31"},
       {"Company":"ABCD","Frequency":"Quarterly","Date":"2016-03-31"},
       {"Company":"ABCD","Frequency":"Quarterly","Date":"2016-06-31"},
       {"Company":"ABCD","Frequency":"Quarterly","Date":"2016-09-31"}
       {"Company":"ABCD","Frequency":"Quarterly","Date":"2016-12-31"}.......]
```

my key schema is:

```
table = dynamodb.create_table(
TableName='table',
KeySchema=[
    {'AttributeName':'Company','KeyType':'HASH'},{'AttributeName': 'Date','KeyType': 'RANGE'}
],
AttributeDefinitions=[
    {'AttributeName':'Company','AttributeType':'S'},{'AttributeName':'Date','AttributeType':'S'}
],
ProvisionedThroughput={
        'ReadCapacityUnits': 100,
        'WriteCapacityUnits': 100
    }
)
```

My Requirements are:

- I need to insert all the rows(as mentioned above) into the dynamoDB ( **Without Overwriting** )
- I know i could add another column as ID (UUID or GUID) as Range key to avoid overwriting.
- But is there any possiblity that i stay with Date attribute as range key (Where i can query with date ranges).Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ConditionExpression` to check for the existing value. The API operation will succeed only if the condition is satisfied.

If the condition is not satisfied, you should get `ConditionalCheckFailedException`.

```
ConditionExpression : "Company <> :companyVal AND #Date <> :dateVal",
ExpressionAttributeNames : {
    '#Date' : 'Date'
},
ExpressionAttributeValues : {
    ":yearVal" : companyVal,
    ":dateVal" : dateVal
}
```

**Primary Key:-**

> The primary key uniquely identifies each item in a table. The primary
>   key can be simple (partition key) or composite (partition key and sort
>   key).

In the base case, the combination of company and date must be unique. It can't have duplicate values.

Comment: Please kindly read carefully my above needs. I said that i need to add both the entries which has same hash key and same range key. Ex:-               
    {"Company":"ABCD","Frequency":"Annual","Date":"2016-03-31"},
       {"Company":"ABCD","Frequency":"Quarterly","Date":"2016-03-31"} 
            But with your answer i could only check and add one item.Got it.Is it possible?Is there any alternate ways?

Comment: Updated the primary key definition.